# Store and query a mapping in a file, without re-inventing the wheel

Tags: shell, mapping

If I were using Python, I'd use a dict. If I were using Perl, I'd use a hash. But I'm using a Unix shell. How can I implement a **persistent mapping table in a text file, using shell tools**?

I need to look up mapping entries based on a string key, and query one of several fields for that key.

Unix already has colon-separated records for mappings like the system `passwd` table, but there doesn't appear to be a tool for reading arbitrary files formatted in this manner. So people resort to:

```
key=foo
fieldnum=3
value=$(cat /path/to/mapping | grep "^$key:" | cut -d':' -f$fieldnum)
```

but that's pretty long-winded. Surely I don't need to make a function to do that? **Hasn't this wheel already been invented and implemented in a standard tool?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case appears to be: **no, there's no widely-available implementation of the ‘passwd’ file format for the general case**, and wheel re-invention is necessary in each case.

Answer (score 1):

Given the conditions, I don't see anything hairy in the approach. But maybe consider awk to extract data. `awk` approach allows for picking only the first, or the last entry, or imposing any arbitrary additional conditions:

```
value=$(awk -F: "/^$key:/{print \$$fieldnum}" /path/to_mapping)
```

Once bundled in a function it's not that scary:)

I'm afraid there's no better way at least within POSIX. But you may also have a look at `join` command.

Comment: Use variable passing instead of trying to keep escaping and quoting straight: `awk -v "field=$fieldnum" '{print $field}'`

Comment: @Dennis: No. In this very case i'm against cluttering the invocation line.

Answer (score 0):

Bash supports arrays, which is not exactly the same. See for example [this guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

```
area[11]=23
area[13]=37
area[51]=UFOs
echo ${area[11]}
```

Comment: You're right, that doesn't apply here. The keys are strings, not integers. Bash >= 4.0 supports associative arrays which might work, but they're still not the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

See [this LinuxJournal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays) for Bash >= 4.0. For other versions of Bash you can fake it:

```
hput () {
  eval hash"$1"='$2'
}

hget () {
  eval echo '${hash'"$1"'#hash}'
}

# then
hput a blah
hget a   # yields blah
```

Comment: Thanks. Arrays don't really help here, because the mapping needs to persist in a file. I've updated the question to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is one of several ways to do this using shell tools. Note that `cat` is unnecessary.

```
key=foo
fieldnum=3
filename=/path/to/mapping
value=$(grep "^$key:" "$filename" | cut -d':' -f$fieldnum)
```

Sometimes `join` comes in handy, too.

AWK, Python, Perl, `sed` and various XML, JSON and YAML tools as well as databases such as MySQL and SQLite can also be used, of course.

Without using them, everything else can sometimes be convoluted. Unfortunately, there isn't any "standard" utility. I would say that the answer posted by pooh comes closest. AWK is especially adept at dealing with plain-text fields and records.